# apache2 virtualhost not working

Tags: apache-2.2

Struggling with getting two virtual sits running on the same IP.
The problem is that it always forwards all requests to the nagios virtual host.
Even when I type in sugarcrm.domain.co.uk it still forwards it to nagios.

Any ideas..... Could it be that my request is not coming with the complete domain name? Or is my config wrong somehow.

These are the only two sits running on the server.

***I have the following files in /etc/apache2/sites-avalable/:***

- opsview
- sugarcrm

**Opsview Config**

```
# This is the apache configuration when running opsview-web over a proxy mechan$
<VirtualHost *>
ServerName nagios.domain.co.uk


#Any files in here will be served by Apache
DocumentRoot /usr/local/nagios/share
<Directory /usr/local/nagios/share>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

# This alias required so that Apache serves NMIS' static files
Alias /static/nmis/ "/usr/local/nagios/nmis/htdocs/"
<Directory /usr/local/nagios/nmis/htdocs>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ProxyRequests Off
<Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
</Proxy>

# Don't proxy error pages as these are served statically
ProxyPass /error_pages !
ProxyPass /javascript !
ProxyPass /stylesheets !
ProxyPass /help !
ProxyPass /images !
ProxyPass /xml !
ProxyPass /favicon.ico !
ProxyPass /graphs !
ProxyPass /static !
ProxyPass /media !
```

**SugarCRM config**

```
<VirtualHost *>
ServerName sugarcrm.domain.co.uk
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php
DocumentRoot /var/www/sugarcrm



        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>


</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: should probably mention that both these are on the same IP and

Comment: I am connecting via the same subnet. Have added the hostnames to /etc/hosts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would try simplifying your configuration and testing that. Something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName nagios.domain.co.uk
DocumentRoot /usr/local/nagios/share
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName sugarcrm.domain.co.uk
DocumentRoot /var/www/sugarcrm
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm assuming you already have a `<NameVirtualHost *:80>` in your Apache config if you're running 2.2.

If that works, then you can slowly expand it and make it more complex. BTW, I noticed that the `<Directory>` directive for your sugarcrm domain points to `/` instead of `/var/www/sugarcrm`.

Of course you can test this using your browser, but another more low-level way to test this is as follows:

- From a machine with a telnet client, type in `telnet server_IP_addr 80`
- When the web server responds (usually with something like `Escape character is '^]'.`)

type in:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
HOST: nagios.domain.co.uk
hit Enter again, so twice after the words in the previous line
```

You can repeat that test for the sugarcrm domain name.

Good reference page: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html

Good luck!

Comment: thanks :) changing both directives to <VirtualHost *:80> did the trick.